# Code Generation : Add primary key / foreign key to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, code-generation, entity-framework-6

I'm using EF with database first approach.

I would like to add attribute to the generated code to mark property as primary key / foreign key when it's the case.

For example, if I have a table `User` in my database

```
CREATE TABLE User
(
   Id int PRIMARY KEY
);
```

I would like my generated code to include an attribute that indicate that `Id` is the primary key.

```
public partial class User
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

How could I do that?

EDIT : I know about T4 template, I just don't know where to start to modify that file.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. The template file you are looking for appears in the Solution Explorer (in VS2013) as:

*YourDataModelName.tt*

You can modify it to add the `[Key]` attributes to the generated code by following:

[Finding a property is Primary Key in POCO Template t4 generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062694/finding-a-property-is-primary-key-in-poco-template-t4-generator)